# How to how show current date and time by default on contact form 7 in WordPress without taking input from user in datetimepicker

Tags: contact-form-7

I have a "Ask for demo" form which has two options, 1. Contact me now and 2. Schedule a demo. 
If user selects option 1 then current date and time should by displayed on form and if he selects option 2 then A calendar is shown for taking user input.
My problem is getting current date and time by default on form.
Please help.
TIA